# Substitute words enclosed between comma or open-parenthesis and comma or closed parenthesis

Tags: regular-expression, substitute, delimiter-matching

I have lines like the following ones (actually function prototypes)

```
void ()
word ( word, another word, one_more word, ..., hello, ... )
one argument ( only )
```

I want to match each single argument and enclose it between `<` and `>`.

Before wasting time with the replacement string, I'm trying to devise the proper search pattern. The following command

```
:%s/\(( \|, \)\(.\{-}\)\( )\|,\)/\1<\2>\3/g
```

only matches and replace odd-position arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your matching groups have overlap! Exept for zero-width pattern items, every charachter in your string will be consumed in the matching. so here you can use `\zs` and `\ze` to confine your match:

```
:%s/\%(( \|, \)\zs\(.\{-}\)\ze\%( )\|,\)/<\1>/g
```

Here i also changed the first and third *captuting* groups to *non-capturing* as we don't need to capture them.
for a complete list of **zero-width** pattern items, see: `:h pattern-overview`

Comment: Oh, this answer is what I was looking for! BTW, while waiting for it I tried another simpler search pattern `%s/ \(\w[^,)]\+\)/<\1>/g`. This is good too, but it fails when something (not necessarly a comment) follows the closing parenthesis. What do you think about it?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis So first capture anything between parethesis and do substitution on them; with your pattern: `%s/(\zs\(.*\)\ze)/\=substitute(submatch(1), '\(\w[^,)]\+\)', '<\1>', 'g')`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However I found another related question [here](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3039/6498).